# How to trigger a submit and get a value from the clicked button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to click a button "wiki", get its value and run the search. I currently have this which starts searching as soon as you start typing.

```
<input id="searchterm" />
<button id="search">search</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```

```js
$("#searchterm").keyup(function(e) {
    var q = $("#searchterm").val();
    $.getJSON("http://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?callback=?", {
        srsearch: q,
        action: "query",
        list: "search",
        format: "json"
    }, function(data) {
        $("#results").empty();
        $("#results").append("<p>Results for <b>" + q + "</b></p>");
        $.each(data.query.search, function(i, item) {
            $("#results").append("<div><a href='http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + encodeURIComponent(item.title) + "'>" + item.title + "</a><br>" + item.snippet + "<br><br></div>");
        });
    });
});
```

I would like to run the search after clicking an external button like:

```
<button class="wiki" type="submit" value="myValueSearchTerm">Wiki</button>
```

I know I can use:

```
$('.wiki').trigger('submit');
```

Yet how do I stop the current search, wait for the `.wiki` button interaction and search for its value?

Comment: A button doesn't have a submit event. Really not enough details given here to understand how this is supposed to work. Is there a form and if so how is it submitted? Need to provide a [mcve] and better explanation of what this other submit is supposed to do

Comment: A value maybe comes from a data-attribute?

Comment: Ok, see update - snippet 3, the data attribute is hardcoded...is that useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UPDATE

OP requests that instead of a text input that a button with an arbitrary value be placed there instead. (see Snippet 3).

---

Register click event to `#search` button instead of the `#searchterm` (see Snippet 1).
or
Register change event to `#searchterm` instead of keyup.

#### SNIPPET 1

```js
$("#search").on('click', function(e) {
    var q = $("#searchterm").val();
    $.getJSON("http://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?callback=?", {
        srsearch: q,
        action: "query",
        list: "search",
        format: "json"
    }, function(data) {
        $("#results").empty();
        $("#results").append("<p>Results for <b>" + q + "</b></p>");
        $.each(data.query.search, function(i, item) {
            $("#results").append("<div><a href='http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + encodeURIComponent(item.title) + "'>" + item.title + "</a><br>" + item.snippet + "<br><br></div>");
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="searchterm" />
<button id="search">search</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```

#### SNIPPET 2

```js
$("#searchterm").on('change', function(e) {
  var q = $("#searchterm").val();
  $.getJSON("http://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?callback=?", {
    srsearch: q,
    action: "query",
    list: "search",
    format: "json"
  }, function(data) {
    $("#results").empty();
    $("#results").append("<p>Results for <b>" + q + "</b></p>");
    $.each(data.query.search, function(i, item) {
      $("#results").append("<div><a href='http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + encodeURIComponent(item.title) + "'>" + item.title + "</a><br>" + item.snippet + "<br><br></div>");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="searchterm" />
<button id="search">search</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```

#### SNIPPET 3

```js
$("#wiki").on('click', function(e) {

  var q = $(this).data('subject');

  $.getJSON("http://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?callback=?", {
    srsearch: q,
    action: "query",
    list: "search",
    format: "json"
  }, function(data) {
    $("#results").empty();
    $("#results").append("<p>Results for <b>" + q + "</b></p>");
    $.each(data.query.search, function(i, item) {
      $("#results").append("<div><a href='http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + encodeURIComponent(item.title) + "'>" + item.title + "</a><br>" + item.snippet + "<br><br></div>");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>





<button id='wiki' data-subject='whatever'>Search for:</button>
<output id='results'></output>
```

Comment: thanks but i don't want an input text but to get the serach term value from the submit button

Comment: Search term value of button? Where is this hidden value coming from?

Comment: There isn't that's why i have asked. Maybe the question isn't clear but i did say i wanted to get the value from a button not an input and i would like this button to be external to the execution code. Otherwise i would just remove the keyup and i'd be fine but i need what i've asked. Thanks a lot tho :)

Comment: The value of button comes from...the sky? Does this value change? Is this value constant? What determines the value of said button? When you want to submit...do mean the submit event of a form?

Comment: It may come from the Sky but that isn't the problem, it's just a string

Comment: My bad, I over think things, happy coding, sir. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `onkeyup` event, this will stop the auto searching functionality.

Change
`$("#searchterm").keyup(function(e) {`

to
  `$("#search").click(function(e) {`
This will search only when you click the Search button.

or `$("#wiki").click(function(e) {` (considering wiki is a button)

Also, you cannot use 'submit' event on '.wiki' button unless it's part of a form.